# Selection field options in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I have to create a new field in one of my forms which is a selection field. How do i make the options in the selection field, entries from another model( like selecting a place from list of places). Do i have to create a new module for such a field? I am using odoo 12.

NB: odoo newbie!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what exactly you want to if possible with example.

Comment: @KevalMehta Ok, take 'places'. the user filling the form(1) has to choose one from the list of places. Now ,i have to be able to add places from a different form(2). So these saved places have to appear in the form(1).

Comment: You need a `Many2one` field, not a `Selection` field. Check out the API documentation https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html. Yes, you need a custom module to add fields. You can also get started on how to build Odoo modules here: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/howtos/backend.html. I suggest you come back and ask when you've started to code and have more specific questions. I also suggest you reading on how to ask good questions on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `Selection` field you have to create a `Many2one` field.You can define a `Many2one` field like ,

```
from odoo import fields

   field_name = fields.Many2one('your.model', string="Field  Name")
```

In your case, consider you have the places in the model `place.place`, then you can create the `Many2one` field in your form like ,

```
   place_id = fields.Many2one('place.place', string="Place")
```